# Track the exact place of a not encoded character in an R script file

Tags: r, encoding

more a tip question that can save lots of time in many cases. I have a script.R file which I try to save and get the error:

*Not all of the characters in ~/folder/script.R could be encoded using ASCII. To save using a different encoding, choose "File | Save with Encoding..." from the main menu.*

I was working on this file for months and today I was editing like crazy my code and got this error for the first time, so obviously I inserted a character that can not be encoded while I was working today.

My question is, can I track and find this specific character and where exactly in the document is?

There are about 1000 lines in my code and it's almost impossible to manually search it.

Comment: While it’s possible that you accidentally included a rogue character somewhere, *in general* you shouldn’t be using ASCII anyway. It’s an old encoding. There’s no good reason to ever use it today (in day to day life; there may be very specific edge cases). In particular, text/code filels should almost always be encoded as UTF-8. I strongly suggest doing this.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph. I'll follow that advise. I was working in Rstudio with everything on default and never paid attention to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `tools::showNonASCIIfile()` to spot the non-ascii.

Comment: Thanks, I tried tools::showNonASCIIfile('script.R') and I get nothing `character(0)` . Could it be possible with that worning that I get?

Comment: I suggest you follow the instructions `To save using a different encoding, choose "File | Save with Encoding..." from the main menu.` and choose `UTF-8` encoding

Comment: I did that, thanks. I'm just worried because obviously I have something in my code that it should not be there, so I need to locate it.

Comment: Ok finally it worked perfectly. I found the character. Thanks @Marcin

Comment: With RStudio on Windows, if I get the warning "Not all of the characters in ~/R/Projects/neuralnets.Rnw could be encoded using ISO8859-1. To save using a different encoding, choose "File | Save with Encoding..." from the main menu." is there a counterpart to the tools::showNonASCIIfile() function to locate the wayward character(s)?

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest two slight improvements this.

Process:

1. Save your file using a different encoding (eg UTF-8)
2. set a variable 'f' to the name of that file. something like this `f <- yourpath\\yourfile.R`
3. Then use `tools::showNonASCIIfile(f)` to display the faulty characters.

Something to check:

I have a Markdown file which I run to output to Word document (not important).
Some of the packages I used to initialise overload previous functions.  I have found that the warning messages sometimes have nonASCII characters and this seems to have caused this message for me - some fault put all that output at the end of the file and I had to delete it anyway!

1. Check where characters are coming back from Warnings!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32610797/69588) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045368/69588) to another question, to check for offending characters in the script currently open in RStudio, you can use this:

```
tools::showNonASCIIfile(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)
```

Comment: Note that you must have actually saved the file first (e.g. with an encoding)